# I want my Discord Bot to send a message a user wrote in the command into another channel -js

Tags: discord.js

Im making a submission bot and i want it to send the message a member wrote behind the pr! command to a different channel.

here is the code for the pr!submit command:

```
const Discord = require ('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();

module.exports = {
    name: 'submit',
    description: "starts the submission process!",
    execute(message, args){

        if(message.content.includes("https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/")){
            message.channel.bulkDelete(1)
            message.guild.channels.cache.find(i => i.name === 'submissions').send('test')

        } else {
            message.channel.send('That was not a link to a CurseForge Modpack, try again!')
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

instead of "test" i want the discord bot to send the link the user included in the pr!submit command into the submission channel.

How do i do that?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What about your args? Can’t you use that?

Comment: I dont know how, thats why i asked, im pretty new to all this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you set up a command handler that defines `args` as an array of user input, such as:

```js
// !command this is user input
['this', 'is', 'user', 'input'];
```

You can use the [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function to join all these elements (with a space between each one).

```js
// !command this is user input
args.join(' '); // 'this is user input'
```

---

Also, [`TextChannel#bulkDelete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) should only be used to, well, *bulk* delete messages (as in delete more than one). If you only want to delete the sent message, you can use [`Message#delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete).

Also #2, you shouldn't create a new client instance in each file, as it won't share the same channels, members, roles, etc. as the original. Also, you won't be able to use any client function because it won't be logged in. Instead, you can access the current client through [`Message#client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client)